# Sorting associative multidimensions array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Can someone please help me with sorting this array from smallest to biggest average in PHP and then it should print only smallest and biggest values in another array?

Explanation of the code will be very appreciated!

Thanks!

```
$students = [
  ['name' => $name1, 'surname' => $surname1, 'avg' => $avg1],
  ['name' => $name2, 'surname' => $surname2, 'avg' => $avg2],
  ['name' => $name3, 'surname' => $surname3, 'avg' => $avg3],
  ['name' => $name4, 'surname' => $surname4, 'avg' => $avg4],
  ['name' => $name5, 'surname' => $surname5, 'avg' => $avg5]
];
```

Comment: This looks offloading an assignment to a (this) community - what did you try, to what avail?

Comment: I am starting to learn php and I had trouble with this sort of multidimensional associative arrays. I spent several hours trying to figure it out, this was last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[uasort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) may provide a solution with the help of a comparison function:

```
<?php

$students = [
    ['name' => "name_1", 'surname' => "surname_1", 'avg' => 51],
    ['name' => "name_2", 'surname' => "surname_2", 'avg' => 42],
    ['name' => "name_3", 'surname' => "surname_3", 'avg' => 33],
    ['name' => "name_4", 'surname' => "surname_4", 'avg' => 24],
    ['name' => "name_5", 'surname' => "surname_5", 'avg' => 15]
];

function compare($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;

}    

usort($students, "compare");

// Sorted array
print_r($students);

// Smaller avg 
print_r($students[0]);

// Higher avg
print_r(array_reverse($students)[0]);
```

Comment: Hu hu… too late ;-)

Comment: Just in time, there is more than one way to skin a cat :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `usort`.

```
usort($students, function($a, $b) { return ($a['avg'] < $b['avg']) ? -1 :
                                            (($a['avg'] == $b['avg']) ? 0 :
                                            1 ); });
```

This function takes the array, and a function that compares two objects and must return

```
<  0 if the first  < the second
>  0 if the first  > the second
== 0 if the first == the second
```

If you want to print the minimum average (after the sorting)

```
echo $students[0]['avg'];
```

The maximum:

```
echo $students[count($students) - 1]['avg'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time!